# Failure to publish WFS layer in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I have created a WFS store in GeoServer and am able to see the layers from the web feature service, when using the 'add new layer' function in GeoServer.

However when I next attempt to publish one of the layers I get the below error. (NB I am able to  publish layers from other WFS).

I am new to GeoServer and web mapping and am having trouble to understand the error message. Any suggestions of what might be causing the error and how to solve it?

[image]

```
> org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of
> interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1@2bcbf573 on component
> [AjaxLink [Component id = link]] threw an exception   at
> org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)
>   at
> org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
>   at
> org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
>   at
> org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
>   at
> org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
>   at
> org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
>   at
> org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
>   at
> org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
>   at
> org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
>   at
> org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
>   at
> org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
>   at
> org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:137)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)     at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)  at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
>   at
> org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
>   at
> org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
>   at
> org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>   at
> org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:90)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:322)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
> sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor542.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
>   ... 115 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred
> while building the resources for the configuration page   at
> org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:423)
>   at
> org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage$9.onClick(NewLayerPage.java:312)
>   at
> org.geoserver.web.wicket.SimpleAjaxLink$1.onClick(SimpleAjaxLink.java:47)
>   at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1.onEvent(AjaxLink.java:85)
>   at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
>   at
> org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
>   ... 119 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: No XSDElementDeclaration found
> for {http://www.opengis.net/wfs}jupiter_boringer_ws   at
> org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getAbsoluteSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:329)
>   at
> org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:296)
>   at
> org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:105)
>   at
> org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildFeatureType(CatalogBuilder.java:342)
>   at
> org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildFeatureType(CatalogBuilder.java:325)
>   at
> org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:413)
>   ... 124 more Caused by: org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: No
> XSDElementDeclaration found for
> {http://www.opengis.net/wfs}jupiter_boringer_ws   at
> org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.parsers.EmfAppSchemaParser.parseFeatureType(EmfAppSchemaParser.java:310)
>   at
> org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.parsers.EmfAppSchemaParser.parse(EmfAppSchemaParser.java:218)
>   at
> org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.DescribeFeatureTypeResponse.<init>(DescribeFeatureTypeResponse.java:64)
>   at
> org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.parsers.DescribeFeatureTypeResponseFactory.createResponse(DescribeFeatureTypeResponseFactory.java:70)
>   at
> org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSRequest.createResponse(WFSRequest.java:215)
>   at
> org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSRequest.createResponse(WFSRequest.java:36)
>   at
> org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.internalIssueRequest(AbstractOpenWebService.java:441)
>   at
> org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSClient.internalIssueRequest(WFSClient.java:313)
>   at
> org.geotools.data.wfs.internal.WFSClient.issueRequest(WFSClient.java:374)
>   at
> org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStore.getRemoteFeatureType(WFSDataStore.java:206)
>   at
> org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSDataStore.getRemoteSimpleFeatureType(WFSDataStore.java:262)
>   at
> org.geotools.data.wfs.WFSFeatureSource.buildFeatureType(WFSFeatureSource.java:364)
>   at
> org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getAbsoluteSchema(ContentFeatureSource.java:327)
>   ... 129 more
```

Comment: Please include error messages as text, not images. This makes them legible on all devices and searchable by future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the WFS has an invalid capabilities response

> org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: No
>   XSDElementDeclaration found for
>   {http://www.opengis.net/wfs}jupiter_boringer_ws   at

without the actual WFS endpoint url there isn't much we can do to help.

**Update**
[image]
Since this is a MapServer installation, you can help GeoServer out by setting the WFS Proxy Strategy to MapServer, and checking the lenient parsing check box.

Comment: Thanks for the quik reply. The  wfs url is http://data.geus.dk/geusmap/ows/25832.jsp?mapname=jupiter

Comment: Brilliant! That worked perfectly! Thanks very much.